# Filter search not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, filter, ui-select

How to filter search work with select option(it still work with text field)
[image]

[image]

```
        <field name="job">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magepow\Importexport\Model\Config\Source\JobOptions</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Job Name</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">job</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">0</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
                </item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">0</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">conditions</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```